# IErrorDataInfo apply tooltip style to all DataGridTextColumns

Tags: wpf, validation, wpf-style, datagridtextcolumn

I'm working in a WPF C# project, I had a lot of problems showing tooltips for validation purposes and I came across this solution in another post here on StackOverflow.

```
<DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="80" ...>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                       Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

and though this works and applies the tooltip style to the columns, I have to paste it in all the columns

I want it to happen... I tried to create a style already but I was unsuccessful. I think it as something to do with the bindings and the "relative source" thing.

Is it possible to create a style out of this and apply it to every column, how do I do it?!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to make it work!

```
               <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="DataGridTextColumnError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

The value binding needed to be changed to static.
Hope this helps someone!